# How to combine multiple tables with the basic ID of one table

Tags: sql, hana

I want to combine 5 multiple tables, that have the same reference ID as the basic table containing all IDs. The "joined" tables are not containing a value for every reference, but sometimes they have multiple values for one reference. The output should be a sum of each value of the ID.

Example:

Basic Table:

| Reference | Basic.Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | d |
| 5 | e |
| 6 | f |
| 7 | g |
| 8 | h |

Table 1:

| Reference | T1.Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | i |
| 2 | j |
| 2 | x |
| 3 | k |
| 4 | l |

Table 2

| Reference | T2.Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | m |
| 5 | n |
| 7 | o |
| 7 | y |
| 8 | p |

Table 3

| Reference | T3.Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | q |
| 4 | r |
| 6 | s |
| 8 | t |
| 8 | z |

Result that should be the output:

| Reference | Basic.Value | SUM(T1.Value) | SUM(T2.Value) | SUM(T3.Value) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | i | m |  |
| 2 | b | (j+x) |  | q |
| 3 | c | k |  |  |
| 4 | d | l |  | r |
| 5 | e |  | n |  |
| 6 | f |  |  | s |
| 7 | g |  | (o+y) |  |
| 8 | h |  | p | (t+z) |

I tried the following code:

```
SELECT 
T0."STATUS", 
T0."DocNum" AS "ProjectNumber", 
T0."NAME", T0."CARDNAME" AS "Client", 
T0."FINISHED" AS "Project Finished", 
T1."PoPhAmt" AS "Project Value", 
T1."PhBudget" AS "Budget", 
(T1."PoPhAmt"-T1."PhBudget") AS "Planned Gross Profit", 
T1."TotalAP" AS "Ordered", 
SUM(T2."PaidSys") AS "Paid Downpayments(Client)", 
COUNT(T2."PaidSys"), 
SUM(T3."PaidSys") AS "Paid Invoices(Client)", 
COUNT(T3."PaidSys"), 
SUM(T4."PaidSys") AS "Creditnotes(Client)", 
COUNT(T4."PaidSys")

FROM 
(OPMG T0 INNER JOIN PMG8 T1 ON T0."AbsEntry" = T1."AbsEntry") 
LEFT JOIN ODPI T2 ON T0."FIPROJECT" = T2."Project" 
LEFT JOIN OINV T3 ON T0."FIPROJECT" = T3."Project" 
LEFT JOIN ORIN T4 ON T0."FIPROJECT" = T4."Project"


WHERE 
T0."FINISHED" < '100' AND T0."STATUS" <> 'N' AND T0."STATUS" <> 'P'

GROUP BY 
T0."STATUS", 
T0."DocNum", 
T0."NAME", 
T0."CARDNAME", 
T0."FINISHED" , 
T1."PoPhAmt", 
T1."PhBudget", 
T1."TotalAP"

ORDER BY 
T0."DocNum"
```

Comment: Hint: `left join`

Comment: I tried left join., but I had to specify the question itself. I meant I need to have a sum over the values with the reference. Sorry for creating confusion...

Comment: Are values `int` or `text`?

Comment: What is the sum of text values? Anyway, to summarize rows you need some aggregation function. [Select one you wish](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/6fff7f0ae9184d1db47a25791545a1b6.html), there are only 14 of them

Comment: value is always `varchar`, specifically it is always a figure in System-Currency (DocTotal). I don´t get with which aggregate-function I could use to summarize figures and to be grouped by the ID of the Basic Table TB."ID".... sorry that I´m not getting it....

Comment: I inserted code in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate before joining:

```
select *
from basic_table t left join
     (select t1.project, count(*) as cnt1, sum(value) as value1
      from t1
      group by t1.project
     ) t1
     on t.FIPROJECT = T1.Project left join
     (select t2.project, count(*) as cnt2, sum(value) as value2
      from t2
      group by t2.project
     ) t2
     on t.FIPROJECT = T2.Project left join
     (select t3.project, count(*) as cnt3, sum(value) as value3
      from t3
      group by t3.project
     ) t3
     on t.FIPROJECT = T3.Project;
```

Comment: Could you specify what T1 after the bracket means?
Is it like:
FROM ODPI T1
GROUP BY T1."Project"
) ODPI T1

?

Comment: Furthermore I added the Code and the errormessage in an answer below.

Comment: @AndréSchwarze . . . It is just a table alias, so you can refer to the results of the subquery like any other table.

Comment: @AndréSchwarze . . . As for the error in your code, the table alias on the subquery needs to match what you use in the `ON` clause.  For instance, you call the subquery `OINV` and then use `T3` in the `ON` clause.

Comment: this is creating all the requested output (+, of course all columns of the basic-table). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT T.ID,T.VALUE,T1.VALUE T_1_VALUE,T2.VALUE T_2_VALUE,T3.VALUE T_3_VALUE
 FROM BASIC_TABLE T
 LEFT JOIN TABLE_1  T1 ON T.ID=T1.ID
 LEFT JOIN TABLE_2  T2 ON T.ID=T2.ID
 LEFT JOIN TABLE_3  T3 ON T.ID=T3.ID
```

Comment: hope, sucessfully

Comment: I tried left join., but I had to specify the question itself. I meant I need to have a sum over the values with the reference. Sorry for creating confusion...

Comment: no problem. But you example looks a little bit unclear for me, e.g. ID=2.In the first table you have value b for this ID, In the Table_1 j and in the table_3 q. But in the outcome you write j+x.

Comment: You´re completly right: ID=2: TB."Value"  = b, T1."Value" j and x (for example two invoices for one project), T2."Value" = "", T3."Value" = q.
So I want to have the sum of each table in different columns for the specific identifier (in this case 2). Have I clarified the issue?

Answer (score 0):

use following query **STRING_AGG** function with group by `Basic_Table.Reference`

```
SELECT 
      T.Reference,
      MAX(T.Basic_Value) AS Basic_Value,
      SUM(T1.T1_Value) AS T1_Value,
      SUM(T2.T2_Value) AS T2_Value,
      SUM(T3.T3_Value) AS T3_Value
FROM BASIC_TABLE T
LEFT JOIN TABLE_1  T1 ON T.Reference=T1.Reference
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2  T2 ON T.Reference=T2.Reference
LEFT JOIN TABLE_3  T3 ON T.Reference=T3.Reference
GROUP BY T.Reference
```

Comment: This is creating a wrong output.... see my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH BASIC_TABLE(REFERENCE,BASIC_VALUE) AS
(

 SELECT 1,  'a' UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 , 'b' UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 , 'c' UNION ALL
 SELECT 4 , 'd' UNION ALL
 SELECT 5 , 'e' UNION ALL
 SELECT 6 , 'f' UNION ALL
 SELECT 7 , 'g' UNION ALL
 SELECT 8 , 'h'
),
TABLE_1(REFERENCE,T1_VALUE) AS
(
  SELECT 1,     'i' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,     'j' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,     'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,     'k' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,     'l'  
),
TABLE_2(REFERENCE,T2_VALUE)AS
(
   SELECT  1,   'm' UNION ALL
   SELECT 5, 'n' UNION ALL
   SELECT 7,    'o' UNION ALL
   SELECT 7, 'y' UNION ALL
   SELECT 8 ,   'p'
),
TABLE_3(REFERENCE,T3_VALUE)AS
(
    SELECT 2,   'q' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,   'r' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,   's' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8,   't' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8,   'z'
)
SELECT B.REFERENCE,B.BASIC_VALUE,ISNULL(T1.R,'')AS SUM_T_1_VALUE,ISNULL(T2.R,'')AS SUM_T_2_VALUE,
 ISNULL(T3.R,'')AS SUM_T_3_VALUE
 FROM BASIC_TABLE AS B
 LEFT JOIN
 (
    SELECT T.REFERENCE,STRING_AGG(T.T1_VALUE,'+')R
    FROM TABLE_1 AS T
    GROUP BY T.REFERENCE
 )T1 ON B.REFERENCE=T1.REFERENCE
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT T.REFERENCE,STRING_AGG(T.T2_VALUE,'+')R
   FROM TABLE_2 AS T
    GROUP BY T.REFERENCE
)T2 ON B.REFERENCE=T2.REFERENCE
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT T.REFERENCE,STRING_AGG(T.T3_VALUE,'+')R
   FROM TABLE_3 AS T
   GROUP BY T.REFERENCE
)T3 ON B.REFERENCE=T3.REFERENCE
```

Not sure about SAP HANA, but in MS SQL Server 2017 this code produces more or less the required output

Comment: This would be suitable if I know beforehand the references and the values, right? That is unfortunatly not the case. The references as well as the values are adding up each day (even within a day)...

Comment: I do not think so. You can add to my example some additional rows and execute the query to see if it is OK for you

Comment: the idea behind that works most likely in MS SQL, but HANA has some specialities. I tried it, but I would say only 80-90% of the code works for HANA. The structure matches almost Gordons answer, which is working. Thank you a lot for your inspiration. It was very helpful!